# Load an external html using vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

how can I load an external html page using Vuejs 2? This is my code in jquery

**html**

```
<div class="main" id="main" style="height: 600px; width: 1200px;">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.main').load('main_template.html');

});
```

I would like to convert this to vuejs 2 if possible, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not simply continue using jQuery? Vue doesn't have a built-in method like `.load`

Comment: @Phil I can but if there is a way to use full vue I think it will be better

Comment: This isn't the type of thing that Vue does. It doesn't have any built-in AJAX stuff

Comment: please read about slots in vueJs

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) directive, but be aware that:

> Note that the contents are inserted
> as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates. If you
> find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink
> the solution by using components instead.

And:

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very
> dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS attacks. Only use v-html
> on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

If it still fit your case, you can use any http library, such as [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), to request the content, put it in a data property, and use it with v-html.